# Bash rename to time

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal, console

How can I rename a file to match the current (rounded) time. If it is for example 10:55 or 11:05 then I would like to rename it to `11`.

Something like this:

```
mv file.txt file_`date +%H`.txt
```

but with the rounding as described above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hour=$(date +%H);[[ $(date +%M) -ge 30 ]]&&let hour++;[[ $hour = 24 ]]&&hour=0;hour=$(printf %02d $hour);for f in *.txt;do mv "$f" "${f%.txt}_$hour.txt";done`

Comment: printf: `%02': missing format character

Comment: @Dado that error means you forgot to specify what format it's looking for, in this case you need a `d` after the `%02`... (probably way too late to mention this, but adding it in case anyone finds this via search)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to round the time to the nearest 3600 seconds.

Generally, to round something, add half a unit, then truncate to that unit; this is easy to do using integer division (divide by the unit and discard the remainder, then multiply by the unit - this will always truncate, i.e. round down, but remember that you already added half a unit).

```
HOUR=$(date -d @$(( ( $(date +%s) + 1800 ) / 3600 * 3600 )) +%H)
mv "file.txt" "file_${HOUR}.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X (BSD date):

```
mv file.txt file_$(date -v +30M +%H).txt
```

On Linux (GNU date):

```
mv file.txt file_$(date '+30min' +%H).txt
```

Both do the same thing: Print the hour value of the current time + 30 minutes.